# Using Exercise 11.1.G. in "The Rising Sea: Foundations of Algebraic Geometry"

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, extension-field

I am trying to use Exercise 11.1.G in "The Rising Sea: Foundations of Algebraic Geometry" (by R.Vakil) to solve the following problem.

**Problem** Let $F$ be a field, $K$ be a finite extension of $F$ and let $\sigma$ be an endomorphism of the set $K^{\times}=K-\{0\}$. If $V$
is an $F$-space spanned
by the set of pairs
$\{(x\sigma(x), \sigma(x)):x\in K^{\times}\}$,
then $\dim_F(V)\geq \dim_F(K)$.

Exercise 11.1.G from Ravi Vakil's FOAG says:  If $X$ is an affine scheme over $k$, a field and $K|k$ is an algebraic field extension, then $X$ is of pure dimension $n$ iff $X_K:=X \times{ }_k K$ is of pure dimension $n$.

Here is my attempt to solve the problem by using Exercise 11.1.G:

Let $F[V]$ be the polynomial ring of $V$, $F[K]$ be the polynomial ring of $K$, $X=Spec(F[V])$ and $Y=Spec(F[K])$.
Then $\dim_F(V)=\dim_F (X)$ and $\dim_F(K)=\dim_F (Y)$.
Let $k$ be an algebraic closure of $K$.
Then by Exercise 11.1.G $\dim_k (X_k)=\dim_F (X)$ and $\dim_k (Y_k)=\dim_F (Y)$.
As $X_k=Spec(F[V]\otimes k)$ and $Y_k=Spec(F[K]\otimes k)$, $X_k=Spec(k[V])$ and $Y_k=Spec(k[K])$.

I guess $X_k$ and $Y_k$ are affine $k$-space. Then I might use dominant rational map from $X_k$ to $Y_k$ to define a $k$-algebra homomorphism from $k(K)$ to $k(V)$.
Since this $k$-algebra homomorphism is an embedding, we conclude that $\dim_k (X_k)\geq  \dim_k (Y_k)$.

However, since my lack of solid fundamentals in Algebraic Geometry, I am not sure what I am trying to do is correct. Even if it is true, I don't know how should I write down the proof properly. So, I need some detailed explanations. Also, I expect an elementary proof without using algebraic geometry.
I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I’m not really sure what you’re trying to do here. Also what is $F[V]$ i.e. what do you mean by a polynomial ring associated to a vector space? Do you mean take a basis and treat the basis elements as $K$-algebra generators?

Comment: What I’m slightly lost on is the set you defined. Why is it a $x\sigma(x)$ in the first coordinate? I feel like that complicates things?

Comment: Yes, take a basis of $V$ and construct a polynomial ring by this basis. $V$ is generated by pairs $(x\sigma(x),\sigma(x))$, so its basis can be chosen as  $(x_1\sigma(x_1),\sigma(x_1)), (x_2\sigma(x_2),\sigma(x_2)),\dots,(x_n\sigma(x_n),\sigma(x_n))$ if $\dim_F(V)=n$. Yes, you are right. I also feel the same way. Also, my attempt maybe wrong.

Comment: Does $V$ defined by the vector space quotient all the linear dependent relation respecting to $F$? like $(1*1, 1)  + 2*(2*2,-2) = (3*3, -3)$ considering $F$ the real number and $K$ the complex number and $\sigma$ the identity?

Comment: I get the definition of $V$ now. It's a subspace in $K \times K$ spanned by the given set.

Answer (score 0):

Is this argument correct? (I am wondering how to solve it with Vakil’s exercise too)

Given $V$ the subspace spanned by
$$
\left\{(x \sigma(x), \sigma(x)): x \in K^\times\right\}
$$
in $K \times K$. One can turn $V$ into a field: define $$(x \sigma(x), \sigma(x)) \cdot(y \sigma(y), \sigma(y))=(x y \sigma(x y), \sigma(x y))$$
Then $V$ is a $F$-algebra. Since it's also a finite dimension vector space on $F, V$ is a field extension of $F$.
Then $K \rightarrow V$ defined by $x \mapsto (x\sigma(x),\sigma(x))$ is also a field extension.
Hence $\operatorname{dim}_F V \geqslant \operatorname{dim}_F K$.

Comment: Hence is a question that I asked on mathoverflow, in that question I give an example to show in some circumstances the problem is correct. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/420421/a-dimension-problem-related-to-an-abelian-simple-extension-of-a-field   @onriv

Comment: I think here you use an addition assumption that $\sigma(xy)=\sigma(x)\sigma(y)$ which is a special case. The $\sigma$ that I defined is just a map from the set $K^{\times}$ to itself. It is not a group homomorphism in general. I am glad that you are interested in this question. Thanks very much for your answer. @onriv

Comment: No problem. Yeah… I did use that assumption. The general case is too hard for me. and maybe it doesn’t hold in general? Try finding some counter example s in case $F$ is finite? @user44312

Comment: The case that $F$ is finite seems won't give us a counter example. I have proved this if $F$ is a finite field. See the website of my first comment. The main problem I have is I don't know that whether my attempt is a right direction and how to construct the rational map that I mentioned in the question. @onriv